# Retrieve data only linked to that session

Tags: sql, codeigniter, session-variables, where-clause

I need to get data where `UserID_Staff`  matched the session `StaffID`

**My query**

```
$this->db->select('Report_Comments.Comments, Report_Comments.Comment_Date staff.Staff_Username')
                ->from('Report_Comments')
                ->join('staff', 'Report_Comments.UserID_Staff = staff.StaffID')
                ->where('UserID_Staff', $this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
            return $result = $this->db->get();
```

**Any Idea why i get this error, and how to change my query ?**

```
 Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`Staff_Username` FROM `Report_Comments` JOIN `staff` ON `Report_Comments`.`User' at line 1

SELECT `Report_Comments`.`Comments`, `Report_Comments`.`Comment_Date` `staff`.`Staff_Username` FROM `Report_Comments` JOIN `staff` ON `Report_Comments`.`UserID_Staff` = `staff`.`StaffID` WHERE `UserID_Staff` = '3'

Filename: models/report/Report_model.php

Line Number: 115
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('Report_Comments.Comments, Report_Comments.Comment_Date ,staff.Staff_Username')
                ->from('Report_Comments')
                ->join('staff', 'Report_Comments.UserID_Staff = staff.StaffID')
                ->where('UserID_Staff', $this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
            return $result = $this->db->get();
```

you miss ',' near Report_Comments.Comment_Date **,** staff.Staff_Username